# connecting Neo4j with java via Eclipse, and query it

Tags: java, neo4j

I am working on connecting Neo4j with Java via Eclipse, when I run the code it works and I got the nodes and their relationship between them, now I need to have a cypher query, I tried many ways but they did not work?

I have looked to [this](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/tutorials-cypher-java.html), but I had an error.

[EDITED]

Here is my code:

```
package testtest;

import org.neo4j.graphdb.Direction;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.GraphDatabaseService;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.Node;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.Relationship;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.RelationshipType;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.Transaction;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory;

public class Testnn {

    // This is the path of the Neo4J

    private static final String Neo4J_DBPath = "/Users/nahla.INTRA/Documents/Neo4j/default.graphdb";


    Node first;
    Node second;
    Relationship relation;
    GraphDatabaseService graphDataService;

    // List of Relationships first knows second 

    private static enum RelTypes implements RelationshipType
    {
        KNOWS
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Testnn hello = new Testnn();
        hello.createDatabase();
        hello.removeData();
        hello.shutDown();

    }

    void createDatabase ()  
    {
        // GraphDatabaseService

        graphDataService = new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabase(Neo4J_DBPath);

        //Begin Transaction  
        Transaction transaction = graphDataService.beginTx();

        try{

            // create nodes and set the properties

            first = graphDataService.createNode();
            first.setProperty("name", "Tom");

            second = graphDataService.createNode();
            second.setProperty("name", "Sara");

            // Relationship 

            relation = first.createRelationshipTo(second, RelTypes.KNOWS);
            relation.setProperty("relationship-type", "KNOWS");

            System.out.println(first.getProperty("name").toString());
            System.out.println(relation.getProperty("relationship-type").toString());           
            System.out.println(second.getProperty("name").toString());

            // success Transaction

            transaction.success();

        }

        finally {
            //finish the Transaction
            transaction.finish();
        }

        }

    void removeData ()
    {
        Transaction transaction = graphDataService.beginTx();
        try 
        {

            // delete
            first.getSingleRelationship(RelTypes.KNOWS, Direction.OUTGOING).delete();

            System.out.println("Nodes are removed");

            // delete nodes
            first.delete();
            second.delete();
            transaction.success();
            }

        finally
        {

        // finish the transaction
            transaction.finish();
        }
    }

    void shutDown ()    
    {
        // shut down graphDataService
        graphDataService.shutdown();
        System.out.println("Neo4J database is shutdown");
    }
}
```

and now I have the query part:

```
try ( Transaction ignored = db.beginTx();
      Result result = db.execute( "match (n {name: 'my node'}) return n, n.name" ) )
{
    while ( result.hasNext() )
    {
        Map<String,Object> row = result.next();
        for ( Entry<String,Object> column : row.entrySet() )
        {
            rows += column.getKey() + ": " + column.getValue() + "; ";
        }
        rows += "\n";
    }
}
```

so,,, first of all how to include the second part of the code to the first one, may be I did not put it in the right place,  the second thing : the error is {result can not be resolved}

Comment: it's not possible to give an answer. What is your code? Which is the error message?

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO, can you please share what you have tried so far (with code samples) and any errors that you faced?

Comment: On which line of code does that error occur?